# PHP mysql how to join two tables to link name from one table and post from other table

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I am very bad at this anyway right now I have this code

```
$test = "SELECT `status`,`pubdate` FROM `status` ORDER BY `pubdate` DESC";
$stmt = $db->prepare($test);
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<section class='statusar'>"."<article>";
    echo $row['status'];
    echo $row['pubdate'];
    echo "</article></section>";
}
```

and it shows the post but now I want to take users first name from another table and display it with the post. How do I do it?

The two tables I have look like this

**This is the table with the post**

```
Status_id  int          unsigned       auto_increment  primary
user_id    int          unsigned index
status     varchar(600)
pubdate    datetime
```

**This is the other table**

```
user_id   int         unsigned auto_increment primary index
firstname varchar(30)
surname   varchar(30)
username  varchar(30) unique
password  varchar(90)
```

I have done so they have a relation between the user_ids

**EDIT**

I think I figured it out because now it works :D
So now when I use

`SELECT status, pubdate,firstname,surname FROM status INNER JOIN user ON status.user_id = user.user_id ORDER BY status.pubdate DESC`

It displays all the things I want and I also tried

```
SELECT * FROM status INNER JOIN user ON status.user_id = user.user_id ORDER BY status.pubdate DESC";
```

Which also works thanks for the help guys :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an `inner join`:

```
SELECT s.status, s.pubdate, u.firstname
FROM status s
    INNER JOIN usertable u ON s.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY s.pubdate DESC
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

This assumes the `user_id` exists in the `usertable`.  If that might not be the case, you'd want to use an `outer join` instead.

Comment: I tried SELECT `status.status`, `status.pubdate`, `user.firstname` FROM `status` INNER JOIN `user` ON `status.user_id` = `user.user_id` ORDER BY `status.pubdate` DESC but it didnt work I also tested with outer join but nothing happend both the status table and the user table have user_id and are in a relation

Comment: @Ghost -- Works fine for me with this condensed fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48a9c/2

Comment: I mean when I use it it displays nothing but if I use the other code it displays the old stuff but if i use the other code that I posted here in the comment it didnt display anything its just empty